# Snap.svg easing in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, gatsby, snap.svg

How would I access `mina` from [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) when using Gatsby?

I can import the `Snap` object through `import Snap from 'snapsvg'` perfectly fine. But when I try to use `mina` or use `import Snap, { mina } from 'snapsvg'` it tells me that "mina is not defined."

My `gatsby-node.js` sets up my Webpack to allow import:

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions }) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: require.resolve(
                        'snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js'
                    ),
                    use:
                        'imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0',
                },
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                snapsvg: 'snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js',
            },
        },
    })
}
```

I would use [Snap.svg-cjs](https://github.com/geelen/Snap.svg-cjs) or [react-snap-svg](https://github.com/janryWang/react-snap-svg) but they seem to be pretty outdated. Any solutions to allow access to `mina` or some other easing function for Snap.svg?

Answer (score 1):

I just did this today and came across your question before I'd worked it out.

The mina package just exports mathematical functions so you can pass your own, linear is the easiest:

```
el.animate(
  { d: paths },
  5000,
  (n) => n, // linear function from mina
  () => {
    // callback stuff
  },
);
```

The rest you can find here: https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/mina.js#L241